# Checkout / Shopping Cart Issues

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, ce-1.8.1.0, shopping

Running `Magento ver 1.8.1.0` and I am having a Checkout issue. In Magento default theme it works a treat no issue but if I enable `Ultimo theme` one areas does not function correctly which is the main checkout update feature. Here is a video of issue will try to attach as well to post.

I know you’re going to say it’s the theme but the developer says cart not touched with theme only CSS style. Plus other user using Ultimo no issue.

Looking for ideas please cannot fix it but i am a newbie at Magento hence looking for help.

Video Link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92887/Shopping%20Cart%20not%20Updating.wmv
Happy Festive Season everybody

Comment: Easy thing: If it is not in the default theme, but in ultimo, it is the theme, check for differences.

Comment: Did you find anyting error info in the system.log or exception log?clear the log and tryin the same and check in logs it will be useful and you can alos try with enabling developer mode.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, the solution was to add the following line to all my templates in cart.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

right after this line:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: HI GUys fixed now i had to re run the patch file and set file permission on patch file

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your theme folder/checkout/cart.phtml file

open it and make sure that form action should be as below. in base file it will come at line no 49.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
```